# I am having a problem with group ownership

Tags: permissions

I am following a group ownership example in *The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction* by William Shotts and I am unable to replicate it.

The example is the following: I created a group called test_group, to which I added two users using `useradd`. I double checked that both users were added to the group using `id user_name.`

Next, I created a directory  in `/usr/local/share` called music. I then did the following:

```
sudo chown :test_group /usr/local/share/music
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/share/music
```

Running `ls -ld /usr/local/share/music` now gives:

`drwxrwxr-x 2 root test_group 4096 Jul 29 12:23 .`

Shotts then goes on to run the following command:
`> /usr/local/share/music/test_file`
which doesn't work for me, despite the fact that we have pretty much the exact same setup. I get permission denied, even though the user I'm logged in to is part of the group test_group. So what exactly is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check the output of `groups` command.

```
man groups
```

> Print group memberships for each USERNAME or, if no USERNAME is specified, for the current process (which may differ if the groups database has changed).

If `test_group` is not there you have to logout and re-login or use any of these commands so system can identify you as a member of `test_group`:

- `newgrp test_group`
- `su - username`
- `sudo -i -u username`

or run the command with specific group:

```
sg test_group -c "echo > /usr/local/share/music/foo"
```